# Blocking calls on WP 8.1

Tags: 8.1, calls, call-sms-filter

How to block calls (and preferably SMS too) on WP 8.1?

Seems that WP 8 had an option in Settings "Call & SMS filter" that doesn't exist at all in this version. No options present in the phone book/calls list. The company tells me they cannot do that. HELP! :/

P.S. if it helps, WP is on model BLU WIN JR W410a.

Answer (score 4):

You should have "call + SMS filter" in settings, using that you can block calls and SMS.

Or in Call History tap and hold to any contact you will have context menu showing,
- details
- delete
- block number...
- add to speed dial.

 I have these settings on my Lumia 525,530
OS Version : 8.10.14219.341 - same in both.

Comment: Hi Nirav! Do not know why, but the block options do not exist - neither in Call history, nor in Settings. Not in WP 8.1 version at least.

Comment: can you please specify your WP 8.1 OS version and Software Release!!! and your lumia device model as well...

Comment: it's not Lumia, it's BLU WIN JR W410a model, operator Open Market Device (BLU), OS version 8.10.12400.899, software WP 8.1. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your windows phone is the latest update..
Before I go to a solution,

### here's my phone extras & info

- Software release = Lumia Denim
- Firmware update notifier 1.2.17.0
- Lumia First Use Experience 1.11.3.0
- Rate Us 3..0.0.6
- SIM Unlock 1.0.0.6
- SpamFilter 1.9.5.2 >> check with your version, same as me or not?

---

If some software is not the same like my phone, then you should download the software namely **SysApp Pusher**, this software use to push notification new update software to your phone.

Then,

- Go to the settings.
- Open, call + SMS Filter, turn ON block call+sms.
- To block number, you just need tap and hold the number (in history or messaging) and block the number it's automatically add the number to "block number list" on call+sms filter.

Fyi, my phone is lumia 720 & os version (8.10.14219.341)

Comment: Thanks RizGuard, found the Call+SMS filer option with the app but says "This app is not available for your device"...