# Blocking calls on my phone

Tags: calls, call-sms-filter

How to block calls? I have looked and cannot find details to do this. I have asked Cortana for help with no success.

Comment: What phone do you have? Is it running Windows Phone 8.1 or Windows 10 Mobile? Have you looked around on this site? A quick search for "block" turned up [this post](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/12625/1401), see if it answers your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blocking calls on WP 8.1](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12625/blocking-calls-on-wp-8-1)

Answer (score 0):

- Go to settings.
- At the very bottom, tap "call+SMS filter".
- Check the "Block calls+SMS" box.
- Now, go to your phonebook.
- Long tap the number you want to block.
- Now, tap "block number..."

And that's how you block a number on Lumia.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 Mobile:

- Go to Call Log
- Long press the number you want to block, a few options will appear and one of them is "Block number"
- Tap Block and Confirm.

The number is blocked.